# Deleting Documents With a Specific Count of Keys from MonogDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have users' collection from which I want to delete the documents which have only 2 fields. My general schema is like this:

```
{
_id: 1,
name: af,
city: asd,
transaction: 1,
transactions:[{
    id:1,
    product: mobile,
    amount: 10
   },
    id:2,
    product: tv,
    amount: 23
   }],
many-other-sub-docs:[],
}
```

I want to delete documents for which only `_id` & `transaction` field exists but not others.

> NOTE: I have around 30-40 fields.

One way to remove those documents is specify all the fields in query which shouldn't exist & only those field which should exist.
For e.g. `db.users.remove({_id:{$exists:true}, transaction:{$exists:true}, other_field1:{$exists:false}, other_field2:{$exists:false}, ...})`
But I find this query absurd. Also I have to find all the fields in my collection.

Is there any other simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well yes there is a better way to do that. I cannot promise you blistering performance, but it's likely not much worse than what you are doing now. You use the JavaScript evaluation of [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/).

The `_id` key is always present, so all you are looking for is testing the presence of another field. The total "field count" for the document is then 2. As in:

```js
db.collection.remove({
    "transaction": { "$exists": true },
    "$where": "return Object.keys(this).length == 2"
})
```

So simply test the length of the array of document keys for the expected value.

Comment: Thanks. That was of great help!